# Getting Runtime error '6': Overflow error

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Code was working fine up until a couple of days ago but now getting the subject-line error.  Help?

```
Sub CopyRows()
    Dim bottomL As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
        bottomL = Sheets("Pacer").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("Pacer").Range("A1:L" & bottomL)
        If (c.Value = "AFSB" Or c.Value = "TEIGIP4T" Or c.Value = "EPP") Then
            Intersect(c.Parent.Columns("A:Q"), c.EntireRow).Copy Worksheets("Portfolio").Range("A" & x + 1)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line actually produces the error?

Comment: If (c.Value = "AFSB" Or c.Value = "TEIGIP4T" Or c.Value = "EPP") Then

Comment: You've probably got a cell that appears as `#######`? Try using: `If (c.Value2 = "AFSB" Or c.Value2 = "TEIGIP4T" Or c.Value2 = "EPP") Then`

Comment: You are absolutely right about the formatting issue where a few cells appear as #######.  Unfortunately, the correction you recommended still produces the Runtime error, but the code works when I manually override the formatting issue.  Is the easiest thing to insert code that would allow me to format the data as it is being copied over?

Comment: Are those cells formatted as Date? If so, the correction I suggested has never failed me before - are you sure you changed **all** the `Value` to `Value2`?

Comment: I did but it looks like the issue was my not using CountLarge along with the formatting problems.

Comment: There's nothing in that code that should require `CountLarge` since you aren't counting all the cells on a sheet.

Comment: Good point, but for whatever reason it seems to be working now so I don't want to chance it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()
    Dim bottomL As Long
    Dim x As Long
        bottomL = Sheets("Pacer").Range("L" & Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("Pacer").Range("A1:L" & bottomL)
        If (c.Value = "AFSB" Or c.Value = "TEIGIP4T" Or c.Value = "EPP") Then
            Intersect(c.Parent.Columns("A:Q"), c.EntireRow).Copy Worksheets("Portfolio").Range("A" & x + 1)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Reason explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-countlarge-property-excel)

Comment: I think we finally got, thanks for the refresh!  Was the issue that I wasn't using CountLarge and/or the Explicit declaration at start?  So frustrating it could come down to something that seemingly trivial

Comment: Because you were not using CountLarge you got a run time error. Explicit is not important here just best practise

Comment: Well thanks so much for the help, really appreciate it.  This is something I use daily so important to get it right.  Muchos gracias!

Comment: One more question, is it possible to augment your code slightly so it only copies values over as to preserve the source formatting in the destination tab?

Answer (score 1):

Variable 
`bottomL As Integer`

Will give overflow error the moment it exceeds 32,767 rows. Try declaring it as long

`bottomL As Long`

Edit: The rule applies to X as well as it is incrementing.

Comment: Gave that a shot, but still running into the overflow error.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here

Comment: What is the value of `x`? Basically, use Long always instead of Integer.

Comment: @SJR Spot on! x is incrementing. I have edited my response.

Comment: I've declared both bottomL and x As Long, but still getting the same error